# JSCH not accepting PKCS#1 keys

Tags: jsch

When we are trying to create a SFTP connection we are getting the below error:

`invalid privatekey: [B@918d45`

This happens only when the key is in the format

`---BEGIN PRIVATE KEY--- (PKCS#8)`

but if the key is in format

`--BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY---(PKCS#1)`

the connection is fine.

From the documentation I can see  JSCH  supports PKCS8 format from 0.1.50 (we are on 0.1.52).
Is there a mechanism by which we can enable JSCH to accept these keys?
Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Show us more of your file syntax.

Comment: formatting for clarity